# Как распределить Uploads файлов через python?

Tags: python

Кто сможет подсказать как выполнить задачу ?

У меня есть файл, в нем находиться 100 строк, также у меня есть 3 сервера.

Из этих 100 строк мы отправляем по 10 строк на каждый сервер, и сохраняем их в файл, где каждый сервер обрабатывает свои строки.
После того как он обработал первые 10x3 строк, у нас осталось 70 строк, и повторяем все по кругу , пока в файле из 100 строк не закончатся строки которые надо обработать.

Может кто нибудь показать пример самого распределения задачи ?

Comment: Не понятно, в чем суть вопроса

Comment: Обработчик принимает строки по одной или пачкой?

Comment: @RomanKonoval тогда лучше мимо пройти

Comment: @eri Обрабатывает пачкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб утилизировать сервера по полной надо отправлять им задачи по мере их выполнения. Вот пример через очередь и потоки.

Несколько импортов:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool 
import functools
```

тут обычные треды, но мне апи multiprocessing нравится больше. Можно всё это сделать через массив с threading.Thread, но зачем, если все уже красиво сделанно в multiprocessing.dummy. Плюс легкий переход процессы, если задача станет затратной по процессору.

Входные данные и функция для загрузки и получения результат

```
servers = ['http://server1.org', 'http://server2.org', 'http://server3.org']
f = open('file.txt', 'r')


def upload(server, chunk):
    pass # реализуйте аплоад тут и дождитесь завершения обработки
```

А вот отправка, пока в очереди есть задания - отправляем их. В конце пришлем индикатор конца очереди

```
def sender(q, server):
    while True:
        chunk = q.get()
        if not chunk:
            break
        upload(server, chunk)
```

Функция для нарезки файла по 10 строк

```
def chunker(q, f):
   chunk = []
   for line in f:
       chunk.append(line)
       if len(chunk) == 10:
          q.put(''.join(chunk))
          chunk = []
   q.put(''.join(chunk))
```

И запускаем. pool.map_async выполняет задачу в отдельном потоке, а нарезка в основном.

```
q = queue.Queue(10) # очередь на 10 по 10 строк
pool = Pool()
pool.map_async(functools.partial(sender, q), servers)
chunker(f, q)
```

Индикатор конца очереди и дождаться завержения работы серверов:

```
for _ in range(len(servers)):
    q.put(None)

pool.join()
```

Comment: Спасибо ! Принцип понял , буду организовывать .

Comment: q = queue.Queue(10) а это точно корректно написано ?

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как вариант - сделать 3 потока. Далее каждый поток поочерёдно должен прочитать из файла 10 строк и записать их в отдельный временный файл, а из основного удалить. Ну и каждый поток выполняет эту процедуру до тех пор, пока строки не закончатся.

К примеру, можно открыть файл через `open` и далее прочитать с помощью `.readlines()`. Это создаст список всех строк и если мы оттуда удалим строки, то основной файл не пострадает. Удалять можно через `del` [тут подробней](https://devpractice.ru/python-lesson-7-work-with-list/#:%7E:text=%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0,%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.&text=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE,%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9%20del%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%5B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%5D.). Ну а далее весь список из 10 значений отправлять на сервак. И так каждый поток, но только на свой сервер. Ну а дальше, думаю, не сложно написать программу по это алгоритму. Также желательно сделать очередь на чтение из списка, иначе два потока могут прочитать одни и теже строчки и одновременно их удалять, из-за чего у одного потока будет ошибка.

Ну, это примерный план по работе программы. Далее вы можете его сами модифицировать.

### Ссылки:

[Потоки](https://webdevblog.ru/vvedenie-v-potoki-v-python/)

[del для списка](https://devpractice.ru/python-lesson-7-work-with-list/#:%7E:text=%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0,%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.&text=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE,%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9%20del%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%5B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%5D.)

[Работа с файлами Python](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html)

Comment: readlines норм для 100 строк, но для больших выборок лучше пройтись итератором. Вместо del лучше делать срезы: `chunk, lines = lines[:10], lines[10:]`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @eri, я понимаю что это лучше, но попытался сделать как раз под запрос в 100 строк и намного проще, чтобы не было более сложных махинаций)

Answer (score 0):

> показать пример самого распределения задачи

Что такое "распределение задачи" я не знаю. Но, по сути, делал бы так:

1. Разработал бы некий протокол обмена сообщениями между клиентом и сервером. Этот протокол содержит всего два типа сообщений: ТУДА (посылаем 10 строк на сервер) и ОБРАТНО (Сервер подтверждает, что он закончил обработку)
2. Разработал бы программу сервера. Она очень простая: ждать прихода сообщения, обработать строки и послать сообщение об окончании обработки. В принципе, в протокол можно добавить некие дополнительные сообщения, например, команду прекращения работы сервера.
3. Разработал бы программу клиента. Она чуть посложнее.

На псевдокоде:

1. Отправить 10 строк серверу № 1
2. Отправить 10 строк серверу № 2
3. Отправить 10 строк серверу № 3
4. цикл пока (Есть не отправленные строки)
5. ```
   Ждём прихода сообщения от сервера
   ```
6. ```
   Определяем - от кого пришло подтверждение
   ```
7. ```
   Этому серверу отправляем очередные 10 строк.
   ```

Я надеюсь, как работать с сокетами в python - объяснять не нужно?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ